# HTML Dynamically Updating Slider Input

Tags: javascript, html

I've never used HTML before and I'm creating a simple website as part of an academic project. I'm using [typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/) and letting the user select the speed of the output. At the moment I'm using a drop down box with options for "slow/medium/fast" that correlate to values used in the javascript code, but I've been trying to implement a [range input](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_range.asp) instead. I'd like a label for the slider to automatically update the selected number as the slider changes, but I'm stuck on how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `oninput` attribute to call a javascript function to update a `label`.

HTML

```
<label id="demo"></label><br>
<input oninput="myFunction()" type="range" id="myRange" value="90">
```

JS

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you are looking for:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input oninput="rangeFunction()" type="range" id="range" value="20" min="0" max="360">

<label id="result"></label>
<script>      
window.onload = function() {rangeFunction()}; //display default  range  value in #result
  
function rangeFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("range").value; //get current range value
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x; // display current range value in #result
}
</script>
```